# Login or email required QuickBlox - Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working on an Android App , Here I am working on Facebook Login using [QuickBlox SDK](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization) . I have implemented this using below code. I have visited many posts on stackoverflow but no luck .

Here is the reference code :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            facebooklogin(accessToken);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error-Check Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

   public void facebooklogin(final AccessToken accessToken) {

        QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {

                String token = accessToken.getToken();

                QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, token, null, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success QB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError QB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

What is happening here , when I login to facebook , then after successfull facebook login I get "OnError QB" toast from onError() method . Can anyone please tell me , what wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: This is an issue with QB backend and Facebook. Will be fixed during next 24h.

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Thank you man for your reply . I am waiting for this fix .

Comment: Hey, can you try it now, we tested it our code sample and it works well. let us know

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Its working now .

Comment: @IgorKhomenko I am working with stickers library version 0.8.2 . I am getting an issue here , Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947603/quickblox-stickers-issue-android . Help me plz .